# CORS policy Error on Netlify but not on localhost

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, heroku, netlify

I have my express server hosted on Heroku, while my react app is hosted on Netlify.
My server has a login route, and whenever I attempt to log in from the client hosted on netlify, I get the below CORS policy error;

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://u-annon.herokuapp.com/api/users/login' from origin 'https://boisterous-churros-56908e.netlify.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

There's no cors error on the GET routes that fetches post, and I don't get this error on localhost, even when I connect the client on the localhost to the server on heroku, the cors setting seems to handle that well, which makes me think this has something to do with netlify hosting. I've been reading about the netlify.toml file, but I can seem to find anything that fixes this problem.

Can someone point me in the right direction pls?
This is my cors setting on the express server;

```
app.use(cors({
  origin: ["https://boisterous-churros-56908e.netlify.app", "http://localhost:3000"],
  credentials: true,
  methods: "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE",
  preflightContinue: true,
  allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization']
}))
```

This is the login post request from the client

```
const LoginSubmit = (e) =>{
        const data = {
            email: email,
            password: password 
        }
        const login = axios.post(`${url}/users/login`, encodeURI({...data}))
                        .then((res) => {
                            if(res.status === 200){
                                parseJwt(res.data)
                                setLoggedIn(true)
                                setLoading(false)
                                navigate('/profile')
                            }
                           else{
                                setLoginError("An error occured, pls try again")
                                return
                            }
                        })
                        .catch((error) => {
                            console.log(error)
                            setLoginError("Email or password entered is incorrect, try again or signup")
                        });
           
            return login
    
    }
```

Comment: Did you figure it out what the issue is? I have a similar issue